# Co/limits and 2-co/limits of categories in the $\infty$- and $(\infty,2)$-category of $\infty$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, limits-and-colimits

Recently, in a conversation with [Gabriel](https://mathoverflow.net/users/131975/gabriel), the following question came up:

> **Question.** Do co/limits of categories taken in the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-categories agree with the usual co/limits taken in $\mathsf{Cats}$, the $1$-category of categories?

We then noticed there are a few variations on this question, due to all the higher-categorical stuff involved:

**Question I.** Let $\infty$-categories mean quasicategories as developed in [Kerodon](https://kerodon.net/tag/003A), and let $\mathsf{Cats}_\infty$ be the [$\infty$-category of $\infty$-categories](https://kerodon.net/tag/0208). Does the functor (I hope there's such a functor anyway)

$$\iota\colon\mathrm{N}_{\bullet}(\mathsf{Cats})\to\mathsf{Cats}_\infty$$
preserve/reflect [$\infty$-categorical co/limits](https://kerodon.net/tag/02VY)?

**Question II.** What analogous statements hold when working with [$(\infty,2)$-categories](https://kerodon.net/tag/01W4), replacing $\mathrm{N}_{\bullet}(\mathsf{Cats})$ by the [Duskin nerve](https://kerodon.net/tag/009P) of $\mathsf{Cats}$, replacing $\mathsf{Cats}_\infty$ by the [$(\infty,2)$-category of $\infty$-categories](https://kerodon.net/tag/020J), and working with the [10+ notions of $2$-co/limits](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386414/), like "lax bilimit" or "pseudo limit", and the respective notions of $(\infty,2)$-co/limits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case of limits is very distinct from the case of colimits. Let me start with the case of colimits.

In general, none of these agree. There is a slight "refinement" of question I which makes it more plausible, namely replacing the $1$-category of categories with the $(2,1)$-category of categories, but it is still wrong.

Note that a negative answer to question I implies a negative answer to question II in full generality, as colimits can be realized as special cases of lax/pseudo/... colimits.

For the variant that I mentioned, the functor from categories to $\infty$-categories is fully faithful, and thus it does reflect the colimits that happen to remain $1$-categories (while this is not true if you ask about the $1$-category of categories).

Let me indicate one type of phenomenon that goes really wrong in all settings: constant colimits. Say you have a group $G$, and are looking at the constant diagram indexed by $BG$ at a $1$-category $C$. In the $1$-category of categories, its colmit is just $C$ (as is the case in any $1$-category!). The colimit in $Cat_\infty$ however, is $C\times BG$.

If $G$ is an ordinary group, this happens to still be a $1$-category and so is preserved under the variant that I mentioned. However, if $G$ was a more general, not -$1$-truncated $E_1$-group, then $BG$ can be an arbitrary space/$\infty$-groupoid, and so $C\times BG$ is no longer a $1$-category, and so the colimit simply cannot be preserved.

This is probably the simplest example, but even most pushouts tend to not be preserved - very special types of pushouts *can* be preserved, and more generally very special types of colimits can be preserved, but they should be thought of as the exception rather than the rule.

As I said, when it comes to $2$-categorical colimits, things get worse.

Now onto limits. Things are much better here. The way you formulated it, it's still generally not true: limits in the $1$-category of $1$-categories are way too strict. So the same "constant" example that I gave before works: in the $1$-category of categories, the limit of this example is just $C$, while in the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-categories, it becomes $C^{BG}$. You might now think that this also gives similar counterexamples in the proposed variant with funkier groups, but you'll now notice that for any $\infty$-category $D$, $Fun(D,C) = Fun(ho(D),C)$ and so the result *is* a $1$-category.

In fact, the inclusion from the $(2,1)$-category of categories inside $Cat_\infty$ admits a left adjoint ($ho(-)$) and thus preserves all limits. Furthermore, this turns out to be an $(\infty,2)$-categorical adjunction, and hence the inclusion actually preserves any type of $(\infty,2)$-categorical limit you might want to consider.

Comment: Thank you so much, Maxime, this is super helpful! :)

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that among the "very special types of colimits" that are preserved are all coproducts.  Likewise, products in the 1-category of 1-categories are also preserved.